# When to loading a proper Loading component in front-end page ?

Tags: javascript, frontend, loading, user-experience

While getting API from back-end, I am facing with a problem: considering the network pending,  I might put a loading component page in the area where will illustrate data before get the data. However, the network speed are fast enough for most json data transmission, this caused the loading page will be loaded in a flash, and this might cause some uncomfortable user experience.

Is there any best practice for loading a loading page？

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use a loading component. Loading times depend on request location, bandwidth, and server load, so one user may experience a 100 ms response time and another may experience 400ms, which can be enough to make a UI feel laggy and abstractly untrustworthy.